# Inexplicable Slowness

Tags: 12.04, freeze, ram, lts

I've been running Ubuntu for about 4 years now, and I'm having a problem with 12.04

Every once in a while the computer will slow almost to a stop, interrupting any playing audio/video, and essentially becomes unusable for a minute or more.
I keep checking the system monitor, but it shows me using less than half of my RAM.
I've got swappiness on 10, the suggested value for my 4GB RAM.
Dell Inspiron 1545, Intel Dual Core 2.1GHz.

I've checked out some of the other threads for help, but nothing seems to work.

Any help?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Also, check CPU usage. I feel that's easier to understand. Do you look at the output of `top` as well?

Comment: Well, damn. I found the problem. Gnome-shell is taking over 80% of the processor at rest. Now to find out how to fix that...

Answer (score 0):

See if anything here will work for you. It worked for me. http://blog.jdpfu.com/2012/09/14/solution-for-slow-ubuntu-in-virtualbox

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.